# Why does 息 mean news?

Tags: meaning, etymology, glyph-origin

Why does 息 mean news?

The chraracter's etymology suggest it means "rest" - 
"From nose indicating breath and also phonetic 自 and heart or chest 心. Meaning to rest."

Source: http://chineseetymology.org/CharacterEtymology.aspx?submitButton1=Etymology&characterInput=%E6%81%AF

So I guess, it is something to do with nose + heart as a metaphor for "interest". It might be understood as "What is dear(heart) to me(nose)"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Over its long history of usage, the meaning of 息 has evolved.

Yes, [`息`](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/xs/606F.htm) has the connotation of `message`.

> (5) 消息 [message]
>   (6) 又如:信息(音信;消息);息耗(消息,信息)

Its original meaning is to `breathe;pant`.

> (会意兼形声。从心,从自,自亦声。自,鼻子。古人以为气是从心里通过鼻子呼吸的。本义:喘气;呼吸)

And then the meaning was extended,

> 人之氣急曰喘。舒曰息。引伸爲休息之偁。又引伸爲生長之偁。引伸之義行而鼻息之義廢矣。

[ Breathing slowly was called `息`, and it extended again to mean `rest`, and extended again to mean `grow`. ]

And then it became to be used with its antonym `消` (`get rid of;eliminate`) as `消息` from pre-Qin period (先秦), means `增减;盛衰` (`growth and decline`), and then extended to mean `变化` (`change`).

Then `消息` began to be used to mean `情况` (`circumstances;situation;condition`).

> 到了魏晋时期,“消息”的涵义则多为“情况”了.
>   任何事物都会有从生长到死灭、从兴盛到衰败的发展变化过程,这种变化过程是一种“情况”.所以“消息”从“消长(生死盛衰)”的涵义演变为“情况”的涵义。

[ By the Northern and Southern Dynasties, 消息's primary meaning was situation. The process of evolution is a kind of situation, so `消息`'s meaning was extended from changing to situation. ]

> 到了南北朝后期,“消息”便又发展出“音信”、“音讯”的涵义,而且从此就成为“消息”最主要的意思.

[ By the later stages of the Northern and Southern Dynasties, `消息`'s meaning was further extended to mean `音信` (`mail;message;news`) and `音讯`.  And that became its primary meaning.]

Reference:
[释息](http://www.doc88.com/p-903537492871.html)
[“消息”的词义演变历程探析](http://xueshu.baidu.com/s?wd=paperuri%3A%285d6583ea4e4e45ce9b2db18fc01a643e%29&filter=sc_long_sign&tn=SE_xueshusource_2kduw22v&sc_vurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.doc88.com%2Fp-6971139996618.html&ie=utf-8)
[从消息到信息──词义的变迁与汉语教学隅例](http://www.doc88.com/p-9025335154065.html)

Comment: Great answer. But I think there's problem saying "息 has meaning of message" – can 息 alone mean "message"? (On the other hand, 消 alone has the "message" meaning as in 《玉篇》 "消，消息也" and in 關漢卿《救風塵》第三折  "兩頭往來，傳消寄信都是我".)

Comment: @Stan It might be hard to say `息` could mean `message` alone, but (1) [zdic.net](http://www.zdic.net/z/19/xs/606F.htm) gives it an item of the meaning `消息 [message]`, (2) besides `消息`, there're `信息`/`息耗` meaning `message` too, so I think "`息` has meaning of `message`" should be fine. (It's not equal to "its meaning **is** `message`" for me. Maybe should say has potential meaning of `message`? Sorry I'm not sure about the English expression here.)

Comment: (1) 汉典 is not necessarily an authoritative source. (2) Oh I see. The different terms for the distinction you mentioned are called **denotation** and **connotation** in English. "Connote" would be the exact English expression there. Yes I agree it's fine to say 息 connotes message.

Comment: songyuanyao, 你的回答相当专业； 我就是担心让学习汉语的人觉得他太难了。。。：） 现代汉语中 单看 “息” 字， 我觉得没有 news 的意思， 必须加前缀 - 消息， 信息， 讯息。。。